# Eclipse milo - Performance/scalability when deploying an OPCUA server in the cloud

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have created an OPCUA server with eclipse milo that is installed in the same machine where the clients are installed, so the communication works fast and reliably.

I did a bit of sniffing with wireshark to see how much communication involves under the hood and apparently there is a lot going on when monitoring variable, alarms, etc....

So I am thinking what issues I may expect in terms of performance and scalability if the server gets deployed in the cloud. I have seen that people talks about OPCUA cloud services, but not being this a hot topic is hard to foresee what challenges may come, and how well it scales and performs.

I would imagine that OPCUA uses sticky sessions, which means that you only can support a max number of users/requests, so dynamic scaling may not be an alternative right?

I tried the samples provides by eclipse milo, which are stored somewhere in the network, and it took long timeto connect to it. If that is the performance one may expect then the perception of the service for non-technical users would be that it does not work well.

Is the cloud a right place to use OPCUA considering the network overhead? Any recommendation to stick to local networks (intranet) only and skip the cloud?

Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @RonyTesler the samples I mentioned can be found at https://github.com/digitalpetri/opc-ua-demo-server. Regarding the application I was working on, I am unable to share the code as it was for a company (private code) that I don't work for any longer. But the eclipse milo demos should help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get into more detail and share Wireshark captures we might be able to go over parameters that would reduce traffic.

If bandwidth is a concern because you're using cellular or other constrained connections then sure, OPC UA may not be the best fit.

I'm curious what kind of delays or latency you experienced running the examples - connecting over the internet generally does not take very long, so perhaps you were also measuring the time it took to compile and start the example or there was something going on with your network.

Comment: As samples I meant the public demo server you have at opc.tcp://milo.digitalpetri.com:62541/milo. I tried again and now it responded faster than a few weeks ago when I tried for the first time. I am connecting by using the Prosys OPCUA Browser. After connecting it feels like rendering the nodes does not happen immediately but takes some time, but I suppose some delay is expected, specially considering that under the last month I have gotten used to have my OPCUA server in my localhost.

Comment: Regarding wireshark I just monitored a bit to see the traffic directed to the OPCUA port and saw several messages being exchanged but nothing specific I could point out right now. I am mostly trying to find what possible problems may come if the server is deployed in the cloud.

Comment: Keep in mind that demo server is running on a single-core lowest-tier Digital Ocean instance in west coast North America and has any number of other clients connected and doing things at any given time. But seeing messages exchanged is normal... not sure why you would expect otherwise. You can reduce the period of the keep alive message and tune the subscription traffic when there is no data changes occurring.